# Loop isn't working correctly. 1st day attempting to write something in app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function myFunction() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Mechanic Sheet #1');  
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Fox');
  target.activate();                                                             
  
  var i = 19;
  var range = target.getRange("B19:B500");
  var data = range.getValues();
 

  for (var i =19; i < data.length; i++){

    if(!data[i][0]){

      var sourceWorkDone = source.getRange("L10:S10").getValues(); 
      var sourceLicensePlate = source.getRange("L13:S13").getValues(); 
      var sourceCompanyProfit = source.getRange("I10").getValues(); 
      var sourceMechanicFee = source.getRange("I9").getValues();

      var targetWorkDone = target.getRange("B"+ i ); 
      var targetLicensePlate = target.getRange("C" + i); 
      var targetCompanyProfit = target.getRange("D" + i); 
      var targetMechanicFee = target.getRange("E" + i);

      targetWorkDone.setValue(sourceWorkDone);
      targetLicensePlate.setValue(sourceLicensePlate);
      targetCompanyProfit.setValue(sourceCompanyProfit);
      targetMechanicFee.setValue(sourceMechanicFee); 

      break;
      
    }
  }
}
```

I have 'Mechanic's Sheet #1' and another sheet called 'Fox' one is the prices and work orders and the second is like a receipt to keep track of work and employee pay.

I need to send the values of L10:S10 of Mechanic's Sheet #1 to Fox B19
I need to send the values of L13:S13 of Mechanic's Sheet #1 to Fox C19
I need to send the values of I10 of Mechanic's Sheet #1 to Fox D19
I need to send the values of I9 of Mechanic's Sheet #1 to Fox E19

but I need to check if B19 is empty if its not empty and contains an already submitted order, i need to send all of data to the next iteration which would be B20,C20,D20,E20.

but i still need it check I need it to check if B19 is empty until it finds an empty spot to plug in the info from the mechanics sheet #1.

It is populating the new sheet with the correct info in slot B19 but it isn't populating B20 with anything and so on. if i change i it will populate the proper spot in the sheet. I can't tell if its the loop or what. First time using this language and would like to see where my mistake is.

Images of First Sheet https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W2wr.png

Images of Second sheet where i need info to loop. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYd2m.png

Copy of Document.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zol7OFwNvkncQfaDSCACFfHZ0ndyb7lBGwtDzjGT2zE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That's because you're using `break` which is breaking the loop on first iteration, can you also share the how your data look like in sheet?

Comment: @vector I added images of the sheet. I need it to break if it runs that IF statement. 

what i want is it to run through the loop add 1 to i , which should then change the range from B19 to B20, then check again if B20 is empty then if it is empty it runs the IF statement and populating the empty columns with the information from sheet 1 and once it places the data i want it to end.

Comment: i also added a copy of what i had

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your problem statement

Try this sample script:-

```
function pasteValues() {   
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssSource = ss.getSheetByName('Mechanic Sheet #1')
  const ssTarget = ss.getSheetByName('Fox')
  
  const sourceWorkDone = ssSource.getRange("L10").getValue(); 
  const sourceLicensePlate = ssSource.getRange("L13").getValue(); 
  const sourceCompanyProfit = ssSource.getRange("I10").getValue(); 
  const sourceMechanicFee = ssSource.getRange("I9").getValue();
  
  const checkEmptyRow = ssTarget.getRange('B18:B').getValues().flat().filter(r=> r).length
  
  const emptyRowRange = ssTarget.getRange(`B${checkEmptyRow+18}`) // get Empty Row adding 18 as your header starts from it
  
  emptyRowRange.setValue(sourceWorkDone)
  emptyRowRange.offset(0, 1).setValue(sourceLicensePlate)
  emptyRowRange.offset(0, 2).setValue(sourceCompanyProfit)
  emptyRowRange.offset(0, 3).setValue(sourceMechanicFee)
  
}
```

- You don't have to use `L10:S10` and so on if cells are `merge`
- Also you don't have to loop through data, just get range and filter
  the non empty range and get the length

**Reference**

[offset](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)

Comment: Bruh your a god send. I'll definately have to study more into some new syntaxes. thank you.